# Checkbox parameters submits but does not INSERT

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Users table I have boolean columns: owner, manager.
The below does not update the table once the form is submitted.

```
  <%= f.check_box :owner %> 
  <%= f.label :owner %>
```

Logs:

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML


Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"k0m814s9fRjCUZxeBXn5GO3o5Fq0evZG1Xc7IfUCOYU=", "user"=>{"name"=>"Bob Dylan", "email"=>"bob.dylan@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "manager"=>"0", "owner"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
Unpermitted parameters: manager, owner
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('bob.dylan@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
  SQL (56.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "password_digest", "remember_token", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Thu, 06 Jun 2013 14:57:53 UTC +00:00], ["email", "bob.dylan@gmail.com"], ["name", "Bob Dylan"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$t5hux4e.jDWS9GH7fJj7Z.gSkLehpJxzfwXOTqbnL6LA7zWZT/11S"], ["remember_token", "J-OFaVfx3a4KMGQ0Q9vttg"], ["updated_at", Thu, 06 Jun 2013 14:57:53 UTC +00:00]]
```

Comment: It's strange that it doesn't update the table, can you check the log and see which parameters are being passed?

Comment: It's in the parameters sent but its not in the INSERT... ???

Comment: Yes, the problem was that you were not permitting those parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your User controller you must have something like:

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:manager, :owner)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Owner: </label><input type="checkbox" name="owner" value="1" />
```

The owner key will be present in the post array if the checkbox is checked.

To make the checkbox checked when viewing the form after the form is submitted, you need to add `checked="checked"` as an attribute on the checkbox element.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to go into your view and create either a checkbox or a radio button for that particular field. In your view, you would do:

```
form_for @user do |f|
  f.label :owner
  f.check_box :owner
  f.submit
end
```

You would wrap this in the html code as needed.